Как реализовать переключение слайдов?
Слайдер привязан к табам в виде модального окна, по клику на стрелку слайдера нужно перемещаться по табам. Как это можно попробовать реализовать? Получилось только криво переходить на один слайд вперед.
    tabsBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        tabsItem[i].style.display = 'block';
        tabsItem[i].classList.add('modals-active');
        projectArrows.addEventListener('click', function(){
            if(tabsItem[i].classList.contains('modals-active')){
                tabsItem[i].style.display = 'none';
                tabsItem[i + 1].style.display = 'block';
            }
            
        })
    });  
}```


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Не понятно, что значит перемещаться по Табам учитывая что вы пишете, что слайд переходит вперед. Это разве не значит перемещаться?

Имеется ввиду, что переход при одном нажатии на стрелку происходит на следующий таб. Если на следующем табе нажать на стрелку, перехода не происходит.

хотя бы схему в паинте нарисуйте
